# Can't start Thread with Buttonclick but with oncreate

Tags: android, multithreading

i have a short Question about starting threads in Android.
I have a class named ClientThread wiich i can start if i do it on create but if i try it with a button click then the App get cloesed. My Goal is it to connect the Client on Click with a Server and restart the Client Thread when the socket is Cloesen. i hope someone can help me.

Here ist the code of the Class Client:

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        TextView socket_stat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.socket_status);
        socket_stat.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

        try {
            EditText ip = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tcpip);
            SERVER_IP = ip.getText().toString();
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            if(socket!= null) {
                socket_stat.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can i start and End the Thread/Runnable with a Click method.

This are the two ways that i have tested:

```
   public void connect(View view) {
    1.Thread thread = new Thread( new ClientThread() );
    thread .start();

    2.new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}
```

I hope Someone can help me.

Comment: what's the error when you start your thread on button click

Comment: how i can track this? i have to run the app on the device cause i use the NFC-Adapter....

Comment: To see the error, connect the phone to your PC right after the app closes and watch the log (you can use logcat from command line to dump the log into a file)

Comment: Did you try by making object of "ClientThread" ?

ClientThread threadObj = new ClientThread();
threadObj.start();

Comment: Yes. It does the same thing. If i start the Client in the oncreate method at the same way it works... "new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();"

Comment: It seems that the thread want start but the app stops imediatly... a colored window show me that the thread jump into the run method.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Log after the App failed.

> --------- beginning of system
>   07-13 13:42:40.341 V/ActivityThread(29240): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{2a21c429 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4f4231 {com.tortel.syslog/com.tortel.syslog.FragmentMainActivity}} show : true
>   07-13 13:42:58.179 V/ActivityThread(29240): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{2a21c429 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4f4231 {com.tortel.syslog/com.tortel.syslog.FragmentMainActivity}} show : false
>   07-13 13:43:50.530 V/ActivityThread(29240): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{2a21c429 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4f4231 {com.tortel.syslog/com.tortel.syslog.FragmentMainActivity}} show : true
>   07-13 13:46:04.755 V/ActivityThread(29240): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{2a21c429 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4f4231 {com.tortel.syslog/com.tortel.syslog.FragmentMainActivity}} show : true
>   --------- beginning of main
>   07-13 13:47:44.417 I/Timeline(29240): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@4f4231 time:2869011
>   07-13 13:47:46.088 D/ViewRootImpl(29240): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
>   07-13 13:47:47.500 D/ViewRootImpl(29240): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
>   07-13 13:47:47.620 D/SysLog  (29240): Enabling log button: true
>   07-13 13:47:49.512 D/ViewRootImpl(29240): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
>   07-13 13:47:49.632 D/SysLog  (29240): Enabling log button: true
>   07-13 13:47:50.563 D/ViewRootImpl(29240): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
>   07-13 13:47:52.705 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29240): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
>   07-13 13:47:53.025 V/ActivityThread(29240): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{2a21c429 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4f4231 {com.tortel.syslog/com.tortel.syslog.FragmentMainActivity}} show : false
>   07-13 13:48:04.466 I/Timeline(29240): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@4f4231 time:2889062
>   07-13 13:48:05.757 D/ViewRootImpl(29240): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
>   07-13 13:48:07.439 D/ViewRootImpl(29240): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
>   07-13 13:48:07.589 V/SysLog  (29240): Path: /storage/emulated/0/SysLog/2017-07-13_13.48/
>   07-13 13:48:07.629 V/SysLog  (29240): Done grabbing logs